# Angular.JS in dynamic JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, dom

Again I... I have stuck. I need to use Angular.JS in my project, but I can't run Angular in dynamic generated tags.

```
    <h1>Your albums</h1><hr/>
    <div ng-controller="AlbumsController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="album in albums">
                {{album.name}}
                <p>{{album.desc}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

That's block, which generated dynamically through JQuery.

```
<html ng-app="Application" class="no-js" lang="ru">
```

That's tag static, and it must init angular.

My dynamic block doesn't work. It returns: {{album.name}}
{{album.desc}}, that's sign of **not initialized** Angular.JS :(

```
var Juster = angular.module('Juster', []); 
Juster.controller('AlbumsController', function ($scope) {    
    $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/myalbums", function(data){ 
        $scope.albums = data; 
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your Controller/Js?

Comment: var Juster = angular.module('Juster', []);

Juster.controller('AlbumsController', function ($scope) {
    $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/myalbums", function(data){
    $scope.albums = data;
    })
});

So, html: <html ng-app="Juster" class="no-js" lang="ru">

Comment: I started creating my project on JQuery, after I remembered about Angular. It helps, display json easily

Comment: Angular can handle this. Drop the DOM creation with JQuery altogether, it'll only cause you problems.

Comment: If you are geneating and inserting those element outside of AngularJS context, you probably need to `$compile` it manually into Angular code. It would help to see more code (escpecially where/when/how are the new elements generated and inserted).

Comment: Ahhh. I know Angular bad, worse than jquery :|

Comment: Take a look at the 2nd example on this page: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.injector

Comment: Agree with @Matt: mixing and matching frameworks will only bring trouble.  Either generate your HTML with Angular (which is what Angular is made to do), or stick with JQuery methods only.

Answer (score 1):

Matt is correct in saying that you need to let go of jQuery for the most part when using angular. It can cause some headaches when working with controllers and directives.

To use only angular in your example I would use the $http service like so:

```
Juster.controller('AlbumsController', function ($scope, $http) { 

    $http({method:'GET', url: '/index.php/profile_ctrl/myalbums'})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           $scope.albums = data; 
        })
        .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
           // Handle error
        });
});
```